# How to update or replace nth position character in Firebird SQL query for the specific column

Tags: sql, firebird

I would like to update or replace nth position character in Firebird SQL query for the specific column, because STUFF is not working in Firebird SQL.

```
UPDATE SYSTEM a
SET 
a.CONFIG = STUFF('FFFFF02FTF', 1, 1, 'T')
WHERE
a.ID = 'AB'
```

Comment: Try Firebird’s [`OVERLAY()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-functions-string.html#fblangref30-scalarfuncs-overlay) function.

Comment: Thank you it is working with OVERLAY() function. but it is not updated in the Config column in the database.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `STUFF` is specific to Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed using [`OVERLAY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-string.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-overlay):

```
UPDATE SYSTEM a
SET 
     a.CONFIG = OVERLAY(CONFIG PLACING 'T' FROM 1)
WHERE
     a.ID = 'AB'
```